# Force spring to use only one connection for transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a spring (version 3.2.15) application that uses more than one connection in a transactional method.

My use case is:

- Call to transactional method (which opens one connection)
- Query for an entity (which opens and closes another connection)
- Persist the entity
- End of the method (closes the first connection)

The problem is that I have a limited number of connections, and I need to ensure that only one connection is used per transactional method. This problem causes a dead lock in my application because there are much more transactions opened than the number of connections available.

Is there any way that I can use the same connection spring uses to maintain the transaction on my method? I have already tried the hibernate option `hibernate.connection.release_mode` in `after_statement` mode, but an error occurs when hibernate is trying to commit the transaction.

I've read the spring transaction documentation but I cannot figure out how to configure spring to behave this way.

Comment: Looks like you have an error somewhere. Query should _not_ open a new connection, unless something's misconfigured.

Comment: Thank you @fdreger. I will revise my configuration. Just wondering, if in the same transaction I perform an entity merge followed by a persist of another entity, what do you expect? In my case, spring opens another connection for the second operation.

Comment: In https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-resource-synchronization it is stated that transactions are synchronized to a connection which is re-usable within the same transaction. Perhaps you can review your transaction propagation choice?

Comment: Thank you @kosgeinsky,I know that. However my application is not behaving that way. I will revise my spring/hibernate/pool configuration in order to figure out why is not following the normal behaviour. My propagation is in REQUIRED mode.

Comment: @PedroPepê: a transaction-scoped entitymanager should not begin a new transaction - that's by definition :-) Are you sure that the method that calls both REQUIRED operations is itself marked as REQUIRED?

Comment: Thanks again @fdreger. Yes, in fact is in the same method, I just call the entity static methods. After your answers I’m sure that the problem lies on my Spring configuration.